# Creating temporary tables with random names in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, random, temp-tables

I wanna create temporary tables with random names in a MySQL stored procedure. I also need to store the name in order to access the table from another stored procedure. I was thinking of using MD5 hashes:

```
SELECT md5(RAND()+CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());
```

I wonder if this will generate totally collision free strings or not?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [uuid()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) and remove the dashes from the result... that is the closest thing I can think of that would give you anything reliably unique.

```
select concat("table_prefix_", replace(uuid(), '-', '')) as unique_name;
```

it would end up being like this:

```
mysql> select concat("table_prefix_",replace(uuid(), '-', '')) as unique_name;
+-----------------------------------------------+
| unique_name                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| table_prefix_39f14dd9418011e3bd86c0cb38cd4f18 |
+-----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```